# const return value of function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, constants

i write the following code, but why the compiler doesn't show warning or error?

```
const computer* const activeComputer = [self.setting getActiveComputer];
activeComputer.name = [service name];
activeComputer.ipAddr = ipAddress;
```

declaration of getActiveComputer function

```
- (const computer* const) getActiveComputer
```

Comment: Is `computer` a `struct` or an object? It makes a difference.

Answer (score 4):

Dot notation in objective-C is short-hand for calling an objects getter/setter methods.  What you have would be equivalent to:

```
[activeComputer setName:[service name]];
```

I would think that calling a method would not violate the const declaration so there is no warning.

Comment: Hi, it seems you misunderstand me, I mean the complider SHOULD give some warning and error for my code, but compiler DOESN'T give any error or warning in fact, I what to know why not.

Comment: Objective-C does not support `const` objects, and the explanation given by @darren is correct. The compiler has no way of knowing, and there's no way to indicate, that a method can or cannot be used on a `const` object. Apple solves this by using mutable subclasses, like with `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: It is confusing to have a class name with a lower case letter in the beginning....

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you mean